# NSSortDescriptor with an array in an object

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort an NSMutableArray by a value which is stored inside a array in the object :)

For better overview i have included the Array. I would like to sort by time (starttijd)

With the NSSortDescriptor i managed to sort by url of status but not by the time.

This is my current code for sorting:

> NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
>           sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"starttuhd"
>                                                        ascending:YES];
>           NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
>
> ```
>     sortedarray = [alleitems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
>     NSLog(@"Sorted array: %@", sortedarray);
> ```

[image: The array]

Comment: what if an object has multiple objects inside `custom_fields` with different `starttijd` dates? what should be picked for sorting?

Comment: And what's your actual code for sorting?

Comment: There will always be only 1 starttijd

Answer (score 0):

First, if there's only ever 1 `starttijd` in the array, then why is it an array?

Anyway, you can try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"@max.starttuhd" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
sortedarray = [alleitems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"Sorted array: %@", sortedarray);
```

Basically, `@max` is one of the KVC collection operators. Since it resolves down to a single element from the array, it may work.